# Run dotnet test with filter and TestRunParameter

Tags: c#

I have autotests in c#, which are integrated with TestRail. In appsettings.Environment.json I have

```
"TestRail": "Local"
```

If TestRail = Local test results aren't exported to TestRail 
I want to run tests with a *--filter* and with a *TestRunParameter*, so that the test results are exported to the TestRail 
I tried:

```
dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Ajax -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"TestRail\", value=\"Report\")
```

but command line doesn't see *TestRunParameter* 
If I try:

```
dotnet test -- TestRunParameters.Parameter(name=\"TestRail\", value=\"Report\") --filter TestCategory=Ajax
```

command line doesn't see *--filter*

How do I run the tests so that both commands are accepted? 
Thanks!